# kivymd MDTextField mode : round - how to change the color of border

Tags: rounding, textfield, kivymd, mode

I am trying to change the border color of an MDTextField - mode:'round'.
I have tried almost anything, but I can't change it!

```
MDTextField:
    mode: 'round'
    hint_text: 'username'
    fill_color_normal: (0,0,0,1)
    text_color_normal: (1,1,1,1)
    line_color_normal: (1,1,1,1)  #This line does not do anything!!!
    text_color_focus: (1,0,0,1)
    line_color_focus: (1,0,0,1)
```

so all the lines are working as expected except line 6! Can anyone please let me know how to change the border color?
if I change the mode to 'rectangle', I don't have a problem, and everything works properly!

Thanks,

Comment: You can try this
    `line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.accent_color`

Comment: Thanks @FaysalAhmed, I tried app.theme_cls.accent_color, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the issue (better to say a workaround). So apparently 'line_color_normal' property is currently not available for 'round' mode.
Instead of using this property, I decided to create a canvas (roundedrectangular canvas) around the MDTextField 'round'. and defined new functions for it.
it works.
you can refer to this link for the solution:
https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/1364

Regards,
Davoud

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).